# how to change the iframe?

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 iframes in my page. Both have the same source. When I change the 1st iframe, the changes must be reflected in 2nd one. It looks like remote browsing. How can I achieve this in javascript?

Comment: Are the iframes in the same domain as the parent? If yes, you need to poll the iframe's location or use postMessage. If No, than you are out of luck.

Comment: yes.Both are in same domain. Can u please give the detail information about this.

Answer (score 1):

```
var iframes = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');

var src = iframes[0].src;
iframes[1].src = src;
```

Without knowing what your page does or seeing any code can't really give you more then this...

Comment: "iframes[0].src" this will return the initially assigned url. When i click some tabs in iframe at that time it doesn't return the actual path.And also i tried "document.getElementById("iframe_id").contentWindow.location.href".But it is return undefined. I can't get the actual path.Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery:

```
var frames = $('iframe');
frames.each(function() {
    this.attr("src", yourUrl);
});
```

Comment: No jQuery tag assigned to the question. Pls. provide pure javascript when possible so that people (especially beginners) do not think it is a dependency for the solution.

Comment: @OnurYILDIRIM: A suitable pure javascript answer was already submitted. My answer supplements it for those who may be looking for a similar solution and are already using jQuery. I must have missed the moderator icon on your profile.

Comment: any solutions in javascript?

Comment: @Balakumar: The appropriate "pure" JavaScript solution was provided by ryan. This method is simply an extension of his concept written to support the jQuery framework.